# How do you convert array of objects to object of arrays based on a certain property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a cors property and I want to make the same cors into separate arrays inside an object.  Here is an example of a response object I get back

```
let response1 = [
  {nameType: "B", cor: "Bol", codeNum: "00210"},
  {nameType: "B", cor: "Bol", codeNum: "00342"},
  {nameType: "Z", cor: "Zul", codeNum: "43021"},
  {nameType: "O", cor: "Ole", codeNum: "040X1"},
  {nameType: "Z", cor: "Zul", codeNum: "45011"},
  {nameType: "Z", cor: "Zul", codeNum: "49108"},
  {nameType: "H", cor: "Hot", codeNum: "5P5X5"}
];
```

Notice how some of the cor values repeat.  I want to break apart this array and convert this into an object that has arrays separated by cors.  Below is the desired output.

```
{
    [
        {nameType: "B", name: "Bol", codeNum: "00210"},
        {nameType: "B", name: "Bol", codeNum: "00342"},
    ],
    [
        {nameType: "Z", name: "Zul", codeNum: "45011"},
        {nameType: "Z", name: "Zul", codeNum: "49108"},
        {nameType: "Z", name: "Zul", codeNum: "49108"},
    ],
    [
        {nameType: "O", cor: "Ole", codeNum: "040X1"},
    ],
    [
        {nameType: "H", cor: "Hot", codeNum: "5P5X5"}
    ]
}
```

Of course doing this for only one is easy enough, how can I do for all of them?

```
function toSingleCorArr(objArr, target){
  return objArr.filter( val => val.cor === target)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to transform your array into an object.

```js
const data = [{
    nameType: "B",
    cor: "Bol",
    codeNum: "00210"
  },
  {
    nameType: "B",
    cor: "Bol",
    codeNum: "00342"
  },
  {
    nameType: "Z",
    cor: "Zul",
    codeNum: "43021"
  },
  {
    nameType: "O",
    cor: "Ole",
    codeNum: "040X1"
  },
  {
    nameType: "Z",
    cor: "Zul",
    codeNum: "45011"
  },
  {
    nameType: "Z",
    cor: "Zul",
    codeNum: "49108"
  },
  {
    nameType: "H",
    cor: "Hot",
    codeNum: "5P5X5"
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((grouped, current) => {
  grouped[current.cor] = grouped[current.cor] || [];
  grouped[current.cor].push(current);
  return grouped;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for `Array.reduce`:

```
...
response1.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (acc[item.cor]) {
        acc[item.cor].push(item);
    } else {
       acc[item.cor] = [item];
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let response1 = [
  {nameType: "B", cor: "Bol", codeNum: "00210"},
  {nameType: "B", cor: "Bol", codeNum: "00342"},
  {nameType: "Z", cor: "Zul", codeNum: "43021"},
  {nameType: "O", cor: "Ole", codeNum: "040X1"},
  {nameType: "Z", cor: "Zul", codeNum: "45011"},
  {nameType: "Z", cor: "Zul", codeNum: "49108"},
  {nameType: "H", cor: "Hot", codeNum: "5P5X5"}
];

var output = response1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const {cor, ...names} = cur;
  acc[cor] = acc[cor] ? [...acc[cor], {...names, name: cor}] : [{...names, name: cor}];
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const resp2 = []
response1.forEach(item => {
  if (resp2.find(subitem =>subitem[0] === item.cors){
    return subitem.push(item)
  }
    return resp2.push([item])
}
```

Your resp2 should contain what you need

PS: I honestly haven't tried this out as I am currently on mobile but logically in my head, this should work.